# Is there a port of the Mixed Authentication Disposition ASP.NET Module (MADAM) for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

The Mixed Authentication Disposition ASP.NET Module (MADAM) is exactly what I need for the project I'm building in MVC2. I'm not an expert on authentication, could MADAM be quickly retrofitted to work with the MVC pipeline?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479391.aspx

[image: Illustrates how the Forms authentication workflow is suspended by FormsAuthenticationDispositionModule, and how BasicAuthenticationModule adds the necessary headers to the outgoing response after FormsAuthenticationDispositionModule has done its job.]

Comment: Have you tried it and faced issue, or is it just a general question before getting to it?

Comment: MADAM seems to provide the functionality I'm looking for in my  project, but before I invest time into it I'd like to know if it's the right direction to go ... can you get it to play nicely with existing forms auth in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your Server Version of IIS, you will need to place the MADAM modules into different locations within your web.config file.

IIS 6

```
<system.web>
 <httpHandelers>
<-- Madam Modules go here -->
 </httpHandelers>
</system.web>
```

IIS 7

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpHandelers>
<-- Madam Modules go here -->
 </httpHandelers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: The section is '<handlers>' not '<httpHandlers>' for system.webServer

Comment: actually it goes into the httpModules section

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into using MADAM for my current project at work as well, however I cannot seem to get it to fire.

It would appear that something has changed in the way that either ASP.Net processes requests and deals with HttpModules or it is a difference in the ASP.Net MVC pipeline.

The quickest solution that I have been able to find is to split the project into two separate projects and host them as different applications in IIS otherwise the authentication will not work as desire.

As far as I can tell if you leave Forms Authentication on, MADAM does not fire and any paths which you wanted Http-Basic authentication for just redirect to the login/or default page. If you have Forms Authentication off then the Http-Basic authentication will work, but the Forms Authentication will not work as it cannot read the .ASPXAUTH cookie automatically.

Unless I stumble across some way to get it working I will have to split this project into two and host each as a separate application in IIS.

If you have any other work arounds they would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used MADAM, but based on the diagram I don't see any reason why you couldn't implement this process in an `AuthorizationFilter` or wire it up directly to `HttpApplication.AuthorizeRequest` event.  ASP.NET MVC is still subject to the ASP.NET `HttpApplication` life cycle.